# Считывание памяти процесса (ReadProcessMemory) | C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Написал небольшую функцию для чтение памяти процесса, но при её срабатывании, программа над которой проводятся опыты вылетает. Что я делаю не так?
Код:

```
DWORD ReadMemory(DWORD address) {
if (!IsBadReadPtr((void*)address, 0x10)) {
    DWORD buffer = 0;
    HANDLE phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, GetCurrentProcessId());
    if (phandle == NULL) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Error with handle", NULL, MB_OK);
        return NULL;
    }
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*)address, (LPVOID)&buffer, 4, NULL);
    CloseHandle(phandle);
    return buffer;
}
else {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Address wasn't finded", NULL, MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}
```

}

Comment: Где именно вылетает? Битность какая x86 или x64?

Comment: x64, это dll, я её инжектю в процесс. Вызываю вот так: MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)ReadMemory(0x01005194), NULL, MB_OK);

Comment: Под отладчиком посмотрите где именно вылетает.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по тому коду, как вызывается функция чтения:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL,(LPCSTR)ReadMemory(0x01005194), NULL, MB_OK);
```

(если она действительно так вызывается), то вылеты вполне возможны (и даже может быть более вероятны, чем нормальное завершение программы), поскольку в функцию [MessageBoxA()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) в качестве второго параметра LPCTSTR lpText (указатель на текстовую строку) передается возвращаемое значение из ReadMemory(), т.е. целое число (DWORD buffer), которое совсем не обязательно является корректным указателем на строку.

Более того, если проверяемая память является нечитаемой (т.е. функция IsBadReadPtr() возвращает TRUE), то функция ReadMemory() возвращает NULL, который по-любому вызовет крах программы при попытке передать его в качестве адреса строки в функцию MessageBoxA().

Если же проверяемая память является читаемой, то функция ReadMemory() считывает 4 байта по проверяемому адресу и возвращает считанное значение как указатель на строку. Вы уверены, что проверяемые Вами адреса всегда содержат корректные указатели на строки? Если это не так, то также получим вылет "Программа обратилась по недопустимому адресу памяти" на вызове MessageBoxA().